# Jersey and spring integration - bean Injections are null at runtime

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, jersey

I am trying to inject services into a Rest class that is using Jersey.

No matter what or how I try to inject into this class seems to be showing up as null at runtime.  Looking in the log files shows that the setJsonTestService is being called when the web app is initialized and that it isn't null at this point.  But, when access it later with a PUT request to this class, it is null.

I am completely baffled.

The class looks like this:

```
@Named
@Path("JsonTest")
public class JsonTest {
    @Context
    Request request;
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    protected final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    private JsonTestService jsonTestService;

    @Autowired
    public void setJsonTestSerivce(JsonTestService jsonTestService) {
        log.info("Setting JsonTestService.");
        if (jsonTestService == null) {
            log.info("JsonTestService is null at injection");
        }
        this.jsonTestService = jsonTestService;
    }

    @Inject
    public ScrapIntermediate scrapIntermediate; // just a plain empty class with an is true method

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void putJson(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        log.info("Putting some json at " + id);
        if (scrapIntermediate == null) {
            log.info("scrapIntermediate is null...");
        }
        if (jsonTestService != null) {
            jsonTestService.sendUpdate();
        } else {
            log.info("jsonTestService is null...");
        }
    } 
}
```

Any ideas?

Update:

web.xml (Jersey)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>EDAS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: How are the web requests mapped to this Jersey class? Sounds like Spring instantiates an instance of this class, but Jersey instantiates another instance to use in handling the requests.

Comment: I've updated the question to show the Jersey portion of my web.xml.  That is the only other place I mention Jersey.

Comment: And solved.  The issue lying with Maven and my Jersey import causing both spring-context 2.5.6 and 3.0.5 to be imported. This caused the annotation conflict and led to the different instantiations of the same class.  Will post it as an answer once it lets me... Thank you for the insight Matt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<servlet-class>
     com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
</servlet-class>
```

You will also need the `contextConfigLocation` `<context-param>`, but I assume you have it. [See here](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/jersey_and_spring) for more details about the setup

As matt b suggested spring instantiates your objects, but Jersey does not know anything about spring and instantiates them itself again. When you use the `SpringServlet` it should locate the spring application context.

That said, spring-mvc provides support for RESTful services that is very similar to that of JAX-RS. You can try it as well.

Comment: Yeah, I was playing around with this and ended up using this when getting it to work.  It just wouldn't let me without the proper Maven exclusions.